# Finding gaps in non-sequential date ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I'm am trying to find a way to compare a serives of data ranges to find gaps, however i need to exclude date ranges that are wholly within another range. Some example data:

```
PERSON_ID  START_DATE  END_DATE 
0001       01/05/2014  30/11/2014 
0001       01/06/2014  01/08/2014 
0001       01/07/2014  01/11/2014 
0001       01/12/2014  31/03/2015
```

I know that i can use the LEAD function to compare one line to the next to see where the gap is if there is one, e.g.:

```
SELECT END_DATE 
FROM 
   (SELECT t.*, 
      lead(START_DATE,1) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE) AS next_date 
    FROM table t 
   ) 
WHERE END_DATE+1<>next_date;
```

The issue is that this would bring back a false positive. The second and third rows of date ranges are wholly contained within the first and therefore should not be included in the gap calculations. I know i need to amend the offset argument in the LEAD function but i'm not sure of an efficient way of doing this for hundreds of person ids. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT person_id
     , start_date + 1 start_date
     , end_date - 1 end_date
FROM
  (SELECT person_id
        , end_date start_date
        , lead(start_date) OVER
            (PARTITION BY person_id
             ORDER BY start_date) end_date
   FROM
     (SELECT person_id
           , start_date
           , max(end_date) KEEP
               (DENSE_RANK LAST
                ORDER BY end_date
                       , start_date
                NULLS LAST) end_date
      FROM
        (SELECT person_id
              , CONNECT_BY_ROOT start_date start_date
              , end_date
         FROM
           (SELECT person_id
                 , start_date
                 , end_date
                 , min(start_date) OVER
                     (PARTITION BY person_id) min_start_date
                 , lag(end_date) OVER
                     (PARTITION BY person_id
                      ORDER BY end_date
                             , start_date) lag_end_date
            FROM mytable)
         START WITH
            (  start_date = min_start_date
            OR start_date > lag_end_date + 1)
         CONNECT BY
                person_id = PRIOR person_id
            AND start_date > PRIOR start_date
            AND (  start_date <= PRIOR end_date + 1
                OR PRIOR end_date IS NULL))
      GROUP BY person_id
             , start_date))
WHERE end_date IS NOT NULL
```

This will merge overlapping ranges e.g. 01-Apr-2014 to 31-May-2014 and 01-May-2014 to 30-Jun-2014 will be treated as a single range of 01-Apr-2014 to 30-Jun-2014. It will also merge abutting ranges e.g. 01-Apr-2014 to 30-Apr-2014 and 01-May-2014 to 31-May-2014 will be treated as a single range of 01-Apr-2014 to 31-May-2014. You will need to alter this query if this is not how you wish to treat these conditions.

Comment: Hi DrabJay, thanks for the suggestion. I have implemented your code as written but it does seem to not work correctly. I have a case with 2 ranges, 31/03/14 - 15/08/14 and 15/08/14 - 31/03/15. I expect 31/03/14 - 31/03/15 but the code returns nothing for that person id. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @ChizoEjindu You have two ranges 31-Mar-2014 to 15-Aug-2014 and 15-Aug-2014 to 31-Mar-2015. These overlapping ranges will, as per my comment, be merged into a single range of 31-Mar-2014 to 31-Mar-2015. Your requirement was "to find gaps". There are no gaps in this single range and hence no records are returned.

Comment: Ah yes I see your point, apologies for my lack of understanding! Now I understand what this is doing I can implement the rest of the code around it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you are getting a false positive, you could turn it into positive by doing something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table t where END_DATE
NOT IN (SELECT END_DATE 
FROM 
(SELECT t.*, 
  lead(START_DATE,1) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE) AS next_date 
FROM table t 
) 
WHERE END_DATE+1<>next_date);
```

I hope it gives you a clue to get what you want without changing your offset arguments.

Comment: Hi Neels, thanks for the comment but i think i haven't explained my issue properly. Looking at the table on a line by line basis the LEAD function would pick up the gap between line 3 and 4 which in isolation is correct. However for the person id this is incorrect as line 1 wholly covers the dates in line 2 and 3 and therefore line 2 and 3 should be excluded from the calculations. The LEAD function needs to calculate only on line 1 and line 4 for this particular example

Comment: Could you please edit your question to give us all a clearer picture.